# Can I remarry a Muslim man without a legal Divorce with my non-Muslim husband?

Tags: nikah, non-muslim, talaq

Assalam walekum,

I had been register married to a non-Muslim for almost 8 years now. Past from 1 year, I am no longer with him as I am asking for divorce mutually after struggling from 1 year now he has agreed and will be applying soon.

Between this, my parents are asking me for nikah to one of my relative whom they have seen for me as soon as possible. My question is I am not legally divorced with my non-muslim husband and if I do a nikah will it be Valid according to Islam and is it legal according to Indian Law. Can my non muslim husband create a problem to us if I remarry?

I am not sure what to do, this time I don't want to disappoint my parents, I'm not sure if my marriage will be valid in Islam

Your advice will be very valuable to me.

nikah

Comment: "Can my non muslim husband create a problem to us if I remarry." This depends on national law, not Islam; Islam does not recognize a marriage between a Non-Muslim man and a Muslim woman.

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Questions are expected to be specific, on topic, and with some research done prior to asking. Please refer to [how to ask a question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and take a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in the [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help).